# Can the expected value of a PMF be zero, as in E[X] = 0?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-variables

The whole question is: 
Let X be a discrete random variable and let Y = 0.5 X + 3.
(i) Assume that the PMF of X is given by
[image]
where k is some suitable constant. Determine the value of k.

(ii) Find E [X] and Var[X].
(iii) Given that X has the PMF found above, find the PMF of Y .
(iv) Without explicit calculation from the PMF of Y , find E [Y ] and V ar[Y ].

---

I have to do this for homework but I'm getting E[X] = 0 and can't find variance either.

**My progress so far:**

`Pr(X = -4) + Pr(X = -2) + Pr(X = 0) + Pr(X = 2) + Pr(X = 4) = 1
k * -4^2 + k * -2^2 + k * 0^2 + k * 2^2 + k * 4^2 = 1
16k + 4k + 0 + 4k + 16k = 1
40k = 1
k = 1/40`

Distribution table:

    `x     | -4  | -2  |  0  |  2  |  4  |
Pr(X = x) | 0.4 | 0.1 | 0.0 | 0.1 | 0.4 |`


Then:

`E[X] = -4 * 0.4 + -2 * 0.1 + 0 * 0 + 2 * 0.1 + 4 * 0.4
     = -1.6 + -0.2 + 0 + 0.2 + 1.6
     = 0`

Is this the correct answer till now? If so, how should I proceed with Var[X]?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are doing fine. Use $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$. You allready know that $E(X)=0$, so it comes to find $E(X^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative for finding $\mathbb E(X)$:

$X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution (by definition $X$ is symmetric) so that $\mathbb E(-X)=\mathbb EX$. This can used as follows:

$0=X+(-X)\Rightarrow 0=\mathbb E(X+ (-X))= \mathbb EX+\mathbb E(-X)= 2\times\mathbb EX$ hence  $\mathbb EX=0$

In general if $X$ is symmetric and $\mathbb E(X)$ is defined then $\mathbb E(X)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the random variable $X$ takes values $x$ and $-x$ with the same probability (i.e. the pmf of $X$ is symmetric about 0), intuitively, we can expect that its average value will be 0.  This can be proved formally using the formula for the expected value:

$E(X) = \sum_x x P(X=x) $

$= \sum_{x < 0} x P(X=x) + \sum_{x>0} xP(X=x)$

$ = \sum_{x >0} (-x) P(X=x) + \sum_{x>0} xP(X=x) = 0$.